Django Unable to Upload Files to NFS Mount
I'm currently working on a project that involves uploading images through Django to an NFS (Network File System) mount, but I'm facing issues where the files are not appearing in the specified NFS directory after a successful upload.
Environment:
Django: Using Django Rest Framework (DRF)
Frontend: React.js
NFS Mount Options: Mounted with rw (read-write)
Access via: PuTTY Running on port: 8000
Current Setup: I have set my MEDIA_ROOT in Django to /testmnt/alltestdata/allimages/test/runner. The upload logic appears to be working, as I can see the image through the API. However, I cannot find the uploaded files in the NFS mount.
Here are the permissions of the relevant directories:
drwxrwxrwx 27 root root 29 Sep 11 07:25 /testmnt/alltestdata 
drwxr-xr-x 4 testadmin testadmin 4 Sep 19 05:59 /testmnt/alltestdata/allimages/test 
drwxrwx-r-x 2 root root 4 Sep 24 01:50/testmnt/alltestdata/allimages/test/runner

I also verified the NFS mount with:
mount | grep nfs
The output shows:
xxx.xxx.x.x:/mnt/DataPool on /testmnt/alltestdatatype nfs (rw,relatime,sync,vers=3,...)
so in my frontend i can upload the image, and also I can also Get it using Postman but the image is no where to be found in the path.
Questions:
Why can I see the images through the API but not in the NFS directory?
What configurations or permissions might I need to change to ensure that Django can write to the NFS?
